# What is the best way to build a stream iteratively?

Tags: java, java-stream

Suppose we have [an algorithm](http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~amana/research/grid.pdf) that generates items sequentially in a loop (one item per iteration) and we want to put this algorithm into a method that returns a stream of those items.

Which approach is best; this one?

```
Stream<Cell> streamCellsTouchingRay(Point2D fromPoint, Vector2D direction){
    // ...
    Stream<Cell> stream = Stream.of(/* 1st item */);
    while(/* ... */){
        // ...
        stream = Stream.concat(stream, /* i'th item */);
    }
}
```

...or this one?

```
Stream<Cell> streamCellsTouchingRay(Point2D fromPoint, Vector2D direction){
    // ...
    ArrayList<Cell> cells = new ArrayList<>(/* required capacity is known */);
    cells.add(/* 1st item */);
    while(/* ... */){
        // ...
        cells.add(/* i'th item */);
    }
    return cells.stream();
}
```

...or another approach entirely?

Comment: Why don't you simple return a list if you're holding all items in memory instead of generating them on demand?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another approach entirely: use [`Stream.Builder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.Builder.html).

```
Stream<Cell> streamCellsTouchingRay(Point2D fromPoint, Vector2D direction){
    // ...
    Stream.Builder<Cell> cells = Stream.builder();
    cells.add(/* 1st item */);
    while(/* ... */){
        // ...
        cells.add(/* i'th item */);
    }
    return cells.build();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- Using an `ArrayList` will have a some copying overhead when you finally get the stream.
- When using `Stream.concat()`, the docs note that you should use caution when concatenating many items:

> Use caution when constructing streams from repeated concatenation. Accessing an element of a deeply concatenated stream can result in deep call chains, or even StackOverflowException.

[Louis Wasserman's asnwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32508977/5322470) seems to be the best, if you are concatenating many items.